# which language is used to develop NES games?

Tags: sdk

I always get fascinated by 8 bit music, game play and sprites includes with NES games how to they program this ? was there an sdk ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Back in the days of the NES, there was no programming language that compiled fast enough to run a good game that pushed the NES to its absolute limits. (It's a combination of the NES not having a strong enough CPU and compilers not being as good back then). Programmers had to write NES games using the same bytecode - set of instructions - that the NES used. Even C is high level compared to this assembly programming.

Here is a great resource from someone who created a NES game in modern times:

The Making of: ROM City Rampage (Retro City Rampage) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hvx4xXhZMrU

Comment: Some nitpicking - they wrote the code in assembly, which technically is a programming language. This is then translated by an assembler into bytecode, which is not human-readable.

Answer (score -10):

[Usually, they're written in C](http://rpgmaker.net/tutorials/227/) - what a surprise (no).

I **hereby demand you** not to just jump into NES game development if you don't even have the ability to google which language(s) can be used to program it. You need to learn programming, learn C *well* (because if you don't, you'll have a hard time figuring out basic language-related problems in parallel with the NES API itself), etc. Making games is not child's play, it requires a lot of learning.

Comment: Well my question was out of curiosity am not jumping into NES game development. I have developed games with pygame and xna am a serious AI developer. I wanted to understand how much hard work is involved in writing games for NES.

Comment: I am extremely doubtful of answers that gleefully claim everything was written in assembly. That's simply madness. This is why compilers are a thing.

Comment: Apart from the gatekeeping, I'm afraid this is just wrong.
Games for the NES was absolutely mostly written in 6502 assembly (which is a language, and it does have a compiler, called assembler). NES games need direct access to predetermined registers and memory locations. Sure you CAN use C, but look at the "hello world" code linked to -- it's so low level it's practically assembly anyway.
The NES has the same CPU as the C64, for which also assembly was used for most game development.
SNES games were sometimes/partially made with C (the SDK was for assmebly). The N64 SDK used C.